# How to test a static class method in MongoDB-Memory-Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, jestjs

I am thoroughly confused on unit testing with mongodb-memory-server and jest. I setup the memory server, [github -  @shelf/jest-mongodb](https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb). I'm using the node driver for mongodb and I have a DataAccessObject class:

```
const chalk = require('chalk')
const ObjectId = require('bson')

let orders

module.exports = class OrdersDAO {
  static async injectDB(clientConnection) {
    if (orders) {
      return
    }
    try {
      orders = await clientConnection
        .db(process.env.DATABASE)
        .collection('orders')

      console.log(
        chalk.magentaBright(
      'OrdersDAO.injectDB() ~~~ line 16 ordersDAO injected DB with client connection....'
        )
      )
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        `Unable to establish collection handles in OrdersDAO: ${error}`
      )
    }
  }

  static async getOrders() {
    try {
      const cursor = orders.find({})
      const allOrders = await cursor.toArray()
      return allOrders
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`OrdersDAO.getOrders() ~~~ Unable to get orders: ${e}`)
      return { e }
    }
  }

  static async addOrder(order) {
    try {
      return await orders.insertOne(order)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        chalk.greenBright(
          `OrdersDAO.addOrder() ~~~ Unable to post order:) ${error}`
        )
      )
      return { error, e }
    }
  }
  static async deleteOrder(orderId) {
    try {
      const deleteResponse = await orders.deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId(orderId) })
      return deleteResponse
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(
        chalk.greenBright(
          `OrdersDAO.deleteOrder() ~~~ Unable to delete order ~~~`
         ),
        error
      )
      return error
    }
  }
```

And my ordersDAO.spec.js

```
   import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'
   import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
   import OrdersDAO, { getOrders } from '../dao/ordersDAO'
   import { mockOrder, mockOrders } from '../mocks/fixtures'

/*
I commented out below because I was trying jests manual mocks,
https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks 
*/
// import OrdersDAO, {
//   mockGetOrders,
//   mockAddOrder,
//   mockDeleteOrder,
//   mockInjectDB,
// } from '../__mocks__/ordersDAO'
// jest.mock('../src/dao/OrdersDAO')

// const getOrders = jest.fn()

describe('insert1', () => {
  let connection
  let db

  beforeAll(async () => {
    connection = await MongoClient.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      poolSize: 50,
    })
    db = connection.db(global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__)
  })
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await db.collection('orders').deleteMany({})
  })

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close()
  })

  test('sanity check', async () => {
    const num = 1
    expect(num).toEqual(1)
  })
  test('should insert a doc into collection, mdb-memory-server', async () => {
    const orders = db.collection('orders')
    await orders.insertOne(mockOrder)
    const insertedOrder = await orders.findOne({ orderId: 'eHjMpYG4o3' })
    expect(insertedOrder).toEqual(mockOrder)
  })
  test('Positive, OrdersDAO.getOrders should retrieve orders', async () => {
    const mockGetOrders = jest.fn()
    mockGetOrders.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(mockOrders))
    OrdersDAO.prototype.getOrders = mockGetOrders
    const orders = db.collection('orders')
    await orders.insert(mockOrders)
    const result = await OrdersDAO.getOrders()
// result is undefined
    console.log(OrdersDAO.getOrders())
  })
})
```

Test number 2 works as expected using the memory server. But I really don't know what that is telling me other than it found a fake order I inserted and not with ordersDAO functionality.

How do I test my functionality in OrdersDAO, like getOrders(), addOrder(), etc? Am I supposed to mock these functions and then use the memory server? Since is is a fake db, do I even need to mock or spy on the static methods?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially I found that I just had to spy on the method and mock a return value.

```
    test('Positive, OrdersDAO.getOrders should retrieve orders', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(OrdersDAO, 'getOrders').mockReturnValue(mockOrders)
        const result = await OrdersDAO.getOrders()
        expect(result).toEqual(mockOrders)
        expect(result.length).toBe(2)
```